# Perl - Building array of arrays leads to overflow

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to analyze a hashmap, for duplicate values and getting their keys in arrays. These arrays will be in an array of arrays. I am a newbie, by the way. However it never stops running when I start it. Where am I wrong?

```
while (($k,$v)=each %hashmap){
        $hasduplicate = 0;
        delete $hashmap{$k};
        @dups = ();
        while (($k1,$v1) = each %hashmap){
            if ($v1 eq $v) {
                $hasduplicate = 1;
                push @dups, $k1;
                delete $hashmap{$k1};
            }
        }
        if ($hasduplicate){
            push (@dups, $k);
            push @dupsarray, [@dups];}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each hash has just one iterator aligned to itself in Perl (see [each](http://p3rl.org/each)). Therefore, running `each` for the same hash in a loop that calls `each` is not doing what you think.

If you want to see what's going on, try adding the following line at the start of the outer loop:

```
warn $k;
```

You are missing several dollar signs before variable names. For example, you probably want to delete `$hashmap{$k}` instead of `$hashmap{k}`, which is equivalent to `$hashmap{'k'}`.

To output an array of arrays, you have to dereference the inner arrays:

```
print map "@$_\n", @dupsarray;
```

BTW, I would use a hash of arrays to solve your task. Here's how:

```
my %dups;
while (my ($k, $v) = each %hashmap) {
    push @{ $dups{$v} }, $k;
}

for my $k (grep @{ $dups{$_} } > 1, keys %dups) {
    print "$k: @{ $dups{$k} }\n";
}
```

Comment: The time taken the loop-within-loop approach is proportional to the square of the number of elements. The time taken by the solution at the bottom is proportional to the number of elements in the hash. The latter scales much much better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there can be only one `each` sequence per hash, as there is only a single index to keep track of the next key/value pair.

In addition, you are using `k` and `k1` in a few places where you mean `$k` and `$k1`. You must always `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program. This would have alerted you to the problem.

You can get around this problem by using `for my $k1 (keys %hashmap) { ... }` for the *inside* loop. This will create a separate list of keys to assign to `$k1` in turn so that there is no multiple use of the iterator.

This modification of your code does what I think you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hashmap = (
  a => 'a',
  b => 'b',
  c => 'a',
  d => 'c',
);

my @dupsarray;

while (my ($k, $v) = each %hashmap) {
  my $hasduplicate = 0;
  delete $hashmap{$k};
  my @dups;

  for my $k1 (keys %hashmap) {
    my $v1 = $hashmap{$k1};
    if ($v1 eq $v) {
      $hasduplicate = 1;
      push @dups, $k1;
      delete $hashmap{$k1};
    }
  }

  if ($hasduplicate) {
    push(@dups, $k);
    push @dupsarray, [@dups];
  }

}


use Data::Dump;
dd \@dupsarray;
```

**output**

```
[["a", "c"]]
```

A much simpler method is to create an *inverted* hash where the keys and values of the original hash are swapped. Then just pick out the values of the inverted hash that have more than one element. This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hashmap = (
  a => 'a',
  b => 'b',
  c => 'a',
  d => 'c',
);

my @dupsarray = do {
  my %inverted;
  while (my ($k, $v) = each %hashmap) {
    push @{ $inverted{$v} }, $k;
  }
  grep { @$_ > 1 } values %inverted;
};


use Data::Dump;
dd \@dupsarray;
```

**output**

```
[["c", "a"]]
```